# Looking for Django Class based views and having multiple forms on a single page examples

Tags: django, forms, class

I have been looking long and far for how to have 2 unique forms displayed on one page using the newer Django class based views method.

Can anybody reference anything? Or provide a basic example. Google is not being my "friend" for this.

Answer (score 8):

The key is that you don't even have to use one of the `FormView` subclasses to process forms. You just have to add the machinery for processing the form manually. In the case where you do use a `FormView` subclass, it will only process 1 and only 1 form. So if you need two forms, you just have to handle the second one manually. I'm using `DetailView` as a base class just to show that you don't even have to inherit from a `FormView` type.

```
class ManualFormView(DetailView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.other_form = MyOtherForm()
        return super(ManualFormView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.other_form = MyOtherForm(request.POST)
        if self.other_form.is_valid():
            self.other_form.save() # or whatever
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/some/other/view/')
        else:
            return super(ManualFormView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ManualFormView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['other_form'] = self.other_form
        return context
```